# Why is routing a request based on its Host header a good way to proxy traffic?

Tags: http, proxy, http-headers, api-gateway, kong

In the [proxy documentation for Kong](https://docs.konghq.com/0.13.x/proxy/#request-host-header), it is mentioned that

> Routing a request based on its Host header is the most straightforward
>   way to proxy traffic through Kong, especially since this is the
>   intended usage of the HTTP Host header

However, for this to work, any incoming request from a client must now have its Host header set to a particular value. In general, HTTP clients don't intentionally modify this value, so how is this used in practice?

In other words, clients aren't in general modifying the HTTP host header in their request, as *is* done in the `curl` examples in the docs, e.g.:
`curl --url http://proxy.mydomain.com:8000/ --header 'Host: service.example.com'`

Given that the proxy is intended to be transparent to clients, why is it the case that 'this is the intended usage of the HTTP Host header'?

Answer (score 2):

If the proxy is transparent to the client, the client usually doesn't know that a proxy is used and therefore resolves the IP Address via DNS. The client then establishes a TCP connection to the IP address accordingly.

The (transparent) proxy now intercepts the traffic. The Host header is now the only chance to get the servers FQDN. This is important if connection is HTTPS so proxy can use the Host header value as SNI / Verify the Server's certificate.

Independent of the use of a transparent proxy, the host header should contain the server name which allows hosting multiple webpages using the same server HW.

Example:

Server IP 1.2.3.4 with 4 websites: www.a.com, www.b.com, www.c.com, www.d.com.

The client must provide the value of the website in the host header in order to allow the server to distinguish between the different websites.